# Python, URL Scanning

Tags: python

I can't find what I need to change in order to make it run, url and cookies are removed for my account safety etc. 
What it is supposed to do is increment the url and tell me if it finds a page that has a string of html in its coding. It just displays error messages.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import re
import os
from random import choice
item = '0'
password= '0'
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [
('User-Agent', ''),
('Cookie', ''),
]
## Login
values = {}
print "",
url = "**************login.php"
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
home = opener.open(url)
#### START LOOP
i = 0
items = 0
page =["*****************&id="]
while x < 900:
    i += 1

    url = page + str(i)
    home = opener.open(url).read()


    #print home
    match = re.search(r"<center>You do not have", home)
    if match:
        link = match.group(1)
        print (page + str(i))
```

Comment: sweet! error messages! ...such as what?

Comment: the error messages would help

Comment: ...and what error messages might those be? You can't expect us to even run your given code, because it's not complete.

Comment: Well to run my code i'd have to give you my cookies, lol. Hold on.

Comment: Line 36 typeerror     url = page + str(i)

Answer (score 1):

The following line:

```
page =["*****************&id="]
```

initialises `page` as a *list* containing one string. When you later do `page + str(i)`, you're trying to add a list and a string, which doesn't make sense. Change the above line to:

```
page = "*****************&id="
```

and you will avoid that error.

Comment: line 31, in ,module. 
home = opener.open(url).read()
protocol = req.get_type()
line 258, in get_type
 raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: =1.0 (Just made the 0.0 into an int but still have other errors)